# Extend Liferay 6.1 polls display to show a specific poll by GET param

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Our portal editors want to share the polls display portlets in other portal content by using the widget url in an iframe.

The problem is they use (most times) the same portlet instances and only add a new question, so the shared widgets will also change.

So our idea was to extend the widget url with a GET param and overwrite the questionId in the JSP for polls_display:

```
// display a specific question
    long questionIdFromParam = GetterUtil.getLong(ParamUtil.getString(request,"questionId"));
    questionId = questionIdFromParam;
```

but the original questionId from init.jsp isn't recognized for getting the preferences as far i can see.